# Enable/disable one radio button based on another radio button

Tags: javascript

I have two radio button groups:

```
<td valign="top" width="37.5%" colspan="3">
```

Actual Days / Month
Only Working Days
Only Working Days + WH
Only Working Days + WH + PH

With name and id the same. My requirement is if I click `ActualDays_Month` radio button, the other two radio buttons have to be disabled.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Please show your full html code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the same name for those buttons that belong to the same group.

```
<input type="radio" name="salarycalenderyears" value="ActualDays_Month" checked="checked" id="salarycalenderyears">
<input type="radio" name="salarycalenderyears" value="OnlyWorkingDays" id="salarycalenderyears1">
<input type="radio" name="salarycalenderyears" value="OnlyWorkingDays_WH" id="salarycalenderyears2">
```

Note that you can't have the same id for more than one element.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I quite understand your question. But the thing is, you want to use radio buttons, they must have the same names with unique ids and values for their identification.